# Configure EntityDataSource from a DAL?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

I am learning Entity Framework 4.

I have a simple ASP.NET (Web Form) application.  I created a separate project for my DAL.  In the DAL, I have created an entity called `Sites`.

Now, I want to bind that to a form using an `EntityDataSource` control but it isn't visible.  What am I doing wrong?

I made sure to reference the DAL.dll in the web project and include it in the code behind for the form.  It's been a while since I've been in ASP.Net  :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reason: The class `Sites` in your DAL project is not `public`. You have only ...

```
class Sites
{
    ....
}
```

... which means that the class is `internal` (identical with `internal class sites`). Then you can reference this class only within the DAL assembly but not in another assembly. You need `public class Sites`.